# My gamecube controller ihas bad input lag when used on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, usb, 20.04, games, adapter

So I am using a Gamecube Controller through an adapter, And the input lag from my Ubuntu system is REALLY bad. I have a strong suspicion that its due to both the type of usb I am using and length of the adapter itself (which when measured is roughly 3 and a half meters in length and uses  a "*White Type A USB 1.x plug*"). Although strangely, It works perfectly fine on my Nintendo Switch with no input lag whatsoever. The adapter I am using is a "DragonRise Inc. GameCube Controller Adapter" and I am using Ubuntu 20.04 lts. Please let me know if there are any questions for additional information, I should be able to respond quickly enough.

```
[37974.086338] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[37974.411713] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=0079, idProduct=1846, bcdDevice= 1.00
[37974.411715] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[37974.411716] usb 1-9: Product: GameCube Controller Adapter
[37974.411717] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: mayflash limited
[37974.436771] input: mayflash limited GameCube Controller Adapter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/0003:0079:1846.0015/input/input58
[37974.436892] hid-generic 0003:0079:1846.0015: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.10 Joystick [mayflash limited GameCube Controller Adapter] on usb-0000:01:00.0-9/input0
[37975.758015] kauditd_printk_skb: 76 callbacks suppressed
[37975.758017] audit: type=1400 audit(1609727698.857:587388): apparmor="DENIED"
```

Comment: do you have another system to test it against to get traction on your hypothesis? what you should do is unplug it, go to the command line, type: `sudo dmesg -c` hit enter, then plug it in, then type `dmesg` and post the results from that.

Comment: Is there a specific section you want me to post? It is very long and I don't want to send every single thing that is in there.

Comment: you ran dmesg -c first (clears dmesg)?  then dmesg once it was plugged in? sure, send it all, put it in pastebin or something. or.... I think this site has some thing for that.

Comment: Let me know if this isnt what you were looking for. Most of the lines just said ``` [37510.544242] audit: type=1400 audit(1609727233.645:579391): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.discord.discord" name="/proc/3017/cmdline" pid=12551 comm="Discord" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```